# Calculate average of pixels in the front buffer of the gpu without copying the front buffer back to system memory

Tags: c++, c, graphics, directx, gpu

I am preparing to build a clone of the ambilight for my pc.
For this purpose I need a way to calculate the average color of several areas of the screen.

The fastest way I have found so far is the following:

```
  pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ddm.Width, ddm.Height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH/*D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM*/, &pSurface, nullptr)
  pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);
  D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
  pSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect, nullptr, D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE|D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK|D3DLOCK_READONLY);
  memcpy(pBits, (unsigned char*) lockedRect.pBits, dataLength);
  pSurface->UnlockRect();
  //calculate average over of pBits
```

However it involes copying the whole front buffer back to the system memory which takes 33 ms on average. Obviuosly 33ms is no way near the speed that I need for a decent update rate therefore I am looking for a way to calculate the average over a region of the front buffer directly on the gpu without copying the front buffer back to the system memory.

edit: the bottleneck in the code snippet is `pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);`.
The memcpy has no visible effect on performance.

**edit:**

Based on user3125280's answer i cooked up a pice of code that should take the top left corner of the screen and average it. However the result is always 0. What am I missing?
Also notice that `pSurface` is now in video memory and thus `GetFrontBufferData` is just a memcpy in video ram which is super fast.

```
  pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(1, 1, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, &pAvgSurface, nullptr);
  pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ddm.Width, ddm.Height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &pSurface, nullptr);

  pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);

  RECT r;
  r.right = 100;
  r.bottom = 100;
  r.left = 0;
  r.top = 0;
  pd3dDevice->StretchRect(pSurface, &r, pAvgSurface, nullptr, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);

  D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
  pAvgSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect, nullptr, D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE|D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK|D3DLOCK_READONLY);
  unsigned int color = -1;
  memcpy((unsigned char*) &color, (unsigned char*) lockedRect.pBits, 4); //FIXME there has to be a better way than memcopy
  pAvgSurface->UnlockRect();
```

**edit2:**
Apparantly `GetFrontBufferData` requires the target to reside in the system memory. So I am back to square one.

**edit3:**
According to [this](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=356) the following should be possible in DX11.1:

- Create a Direct3D 11.1 device. (Maybe earlier works too -- I haven't tried. I'm not sure there's a reason to use a D3D10/10.1/11 device anyway.)
- Find the IDXGIOutput you want to duplicate, and call DuplicateOutput() to get an IDXGIOutputDuplication interface.
- Call AcquireNextFrame() to wait for a new frame to arrive.
- Process the received texture.
- Call ReleaseFrame().
- Repeat.

However due to my non existing knowledge of DirectX I am having a hard time implementing it.

**edit4:**
DuplicateOutput is not supported in operating systems older than Windows 8 :(

**edit5:**
I did some experiments with the classical `GetPixel` API thinking that it may be fast enough for random sampling. Sadly it is not. `GetPixel` takes the same amount of time that `GetFrontBufferData` takes. I guess it internally calls `GetFrontBufferData`.

So for now I see two solutions:
 * Disable Aero and use `GetFrontBufferData`
 * Switch to windows 8
Both of them are not really good :(

Comment: sounds great, what are you using for the lighting? and are you sure you can grab the whole screen with a background process? like this one http://amblone.com/?

Comment: Can you bind his buffer as a texture and do calculations in pixel shader?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819951/how-to-copy-frontbuffer-data-to-texture-directx-9

Comment: @◙user3125280  I am planning to use [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12025) led rgb strip driven by an Arduino. Yes just like the amblone one. But I want to code it myself :D Acutually the code snippet I posted is nearly identical to the code that amblone uses.

Comment: a much faster alternative would be to sample points randomly, and keep a moving average

Comment: @ArneBöckmann good - i was crossing my fingers it wasn't more raspberry pi overkill

Comment: @user3125280   That would indeed by much faster, however I would still need to copy the front buffer back to system memory to do so. I ll go and check how much faster the code gets when I copy only a small part of the buffer.

Comment: @Drop I have never done any shader programing. Any hints on where to start looking for good tutorials?

Comment: @Arne no shading? how else were you going to sum on the gpu? Still my answer doesn't require shaders, and you only copy the resulting sum back to cpu. Also, in opengl at least, there is usually some abstraction to access a fex pixel. But only try that if the other way is too slow

Comment: Stupid question.  If you downsample the frontbuffer to 1 pixel, then blow it back up, would that work?

Comment: @Proxy how should I downsample the front buffer? I do not know of any way to get a 'handle' to the front buffer without copying it to system memory.

Comment: This is DirectX 11, no?  This is a large article, but it shows how to do that.  http://rastertek.com/dx11tut36.html

Comment: @Proxy The tutorial renders it's own scene and blurs it by downsampling. The downsampling is a nice way to calculate the average. However it does not solve my performance problem because I still need to load the screen content into a texture (which is not possible without moving through system ram)

Answer (score 3):

This problem is actually common (apparently) in game code and the like. One interesting solution is the following: [Efficient pixel shader sum of all pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944290/efficient-pixel-shader-sum-of-all-pixels). This is particularly relevant to your exact situation, since you can use a larger mimmap texture to sum smaller segments of the display.

[Get the screen into a texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819951/how-to-copy-frontbuffer-data-to-texture-directx-9)

```
IDirect3DTexture9* texture; // needs to be created, of course
IDirect3DSurface9* dest = NULL; // to be our level0 surface of the texture
texture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &dest);
pD3DDevice->StretchRect(pSurface, NULL, dest, NULL, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
```

And then create a mipmap chain as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
// This code example assumes that m_d3dDevice is a
// valid pointer to a IDirect3DDevice9 interface

IDirect3DTexture9 * pMipMap;
m_pD3DDevice->CreateTexture(256, 256, 5, 0, D3DFMT_R8G8B8, 
D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &pMipMap);
```

Of course you don't have to access the bottom mipmap (which is the average). You could access a few levels higher to get averages of sections. Also this is quick because texture mipmapping is important in games and graphics in general. Other filtering options may be available too.

For the second edit try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120066/doing-readback-from-direct3d-textures-and-surfaces) - something about textures in gpu mem are read differently, and can't be locked, you'll need to use getrendertargetdata or some such. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174405%28VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to copy your stretchrect surface to a texture created cpu side in the system pool. As far as I know gpu side textures/surfaces can't be memcpy'ed directly.

Comment: Thx! this is definitely a huge pointer in the right direction. However I really don't need all the levels, just the last one. Therefore I tried to cook something up based on StrechRect(). (see edit in question)

Comment: this as far as i can lead, i've only ever tried my hand at open gl graphics and i'm, not familiar with how to manipulate d3d textures. i can only tell you what's in the docs

Comment: @Arne what happens when you replace &r with null in strechrect?

Comment: The same happens. Also I just noticed that the method returns D3DERR_INVALIDCALL. So I guess something is wrong with the initialization.

Comment: @Arne is the stretchrect method invalid? see my edit

Comment: @Arne this is cause of invalidity "The source and destination surfaces must be created in the default memory pool." for stretchrect. just replace scratch pool with default :)

Comment: Sadly not, I found that bug 2 minutes ago but it didnt change anything :( Method call is still invalid. But at the very bottom of the documentation is a table that states that I cannot use Off-screen plain as src and destination.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43931/discussion-between-user3125280-and-arne-bockmann)